# Bot not responding to commands (discord.js v12)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've tried doing a test command using `client.on` which worked but everything else in my command handler does not work. Nothing is returned, is there something I am doing wrong?

**Issue**: My ping command does not do anything whatsoever.

Index.js file

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');
const fs = require("fs");
const client = new Client({ disableMentions: 'everyone', partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'], ws: { intents: Intents.ALL } });
const PREFIX = config.PREFIX;
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./commands/")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

  for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
  }
  
client.commands = new Collection();
```

Ping file

```
let config = require('../config.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    category: 'Info',
    description: 'Returns the bot\'s latency and API ping.',
    aliases: ['latency'],
    usage: 'ping',
    userperms: [],
    botperms: [],
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        message.channel.send(' Pinging....').then((msg) => {
            const pEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(' Pong!')
                .setColor('BLUE')
                .setDescription(
                    `Latency: ${Math.floor(
                        msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp,
                    )}ms\nAPI Latency: ${client.ws.ping}ms`,
                );
            msg.edit(pEmbed);
        });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add event which will trigger every time a message is created and the bot can see it.

An example on version 12 would be (using [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) :

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("!ping")) {
    message.channel.send('Pong!');
  }
});
```

In v13, [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v13/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) is deprecated so use [`messageCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.1.0/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) :

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("!ping")) {
    message.channel.send('Pong!');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not the issue though, I did this beforehand and it worked fine. My issue is that bot does not return anything for `module.exports`

Comment: @ignshifts You mean that you can't access the module on the file of the command ?-?

Comment: Yea, it does nothing

Comment: @ignshifts what exactly does nothing, did you try `if(message.content.startsWith('!ping') { client.commands.get('ping`).execute(client,message,args) }` or something so that the code on the file actually runs on the event

Comment: The ping file, when I run the command nothing happens. I am not talking about creating a command on a event or message event; I did that beforehand like I said before and it worked.

Comment: Oh then the problem is from your main file, maybe you can actually edit your question and show the current file, with the client.on (removing the things that don't have to do anything with the command if you want)

Comment: Most of the things are already in the index file which is my main file, I just added the MessageEvent command.

Comment: In what you just added there's nothing to actually run the command file and the execute function in it :^